# "IndexError: list index out of range" error

Tags: python

```
for i in guess:
    if i == number[idx]:
        print("Cow")
    idx = idx + 1
```

guess and number are both string lists. I want to compare each individual character in each list with the same index number.

I keep getting the error of
"if i == number[idx]:
IndexError: list index out of range"
Why's that?

(idx = 0)

Comment: Please review how to make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Dummy placeholder values are needed so we can paste your code into our IDE and test it.

Comment: what are the length of `guess` and `number` list. It's clear that you are accessing more than you should

Comment: What is the number list? If it is empty, then that might be your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating idx to idx+1 everytime you iterate the list. If the length of guess is greater than len of number then idx will also get updated greater than the len of number and it'll give you out of range error. Be sure with the length of number and guesses

Comment: yup I see where I went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to know that my answer helped. You can accept my answer 